# Python - Convert DB resultset to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, resultset

I have a multi columns result set returning from a query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, IS_PARTITIONED, IS_APPEND FROM TABLES_MANAGER;
```

I need help to convert it to a dictionary using the `TABLE_NAME` column as the dictionary key.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `resultset`?

Comment: the rows and columns returning from the DB query.

Comment: Which library are you using? Please include a link to it.

Comment: Still looking for the right one, now I am using:
import json
import csv
import os
import pyodbc

Comment: Which database are you using? Also, a snippet of your code the way it looks now would be useful.

Comment: I worked around this with:
 `result = exacur.fetchall()  

       tdict= {}  

       for row in result:  

           key=row[0]  

           tdict[key]=[row[1],row[2]]  
`